# http://localhost:3000/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, passport.js

My code is working fine on POSTMAN, But when i'm trying on browser it shows this error in the console:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)
```

i am trying to authenticate with PASSPORT JWT.
my auth route:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/profile
```

my passport config file:

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const database = require("./database");
const User = require("../model/model");

module.exports = (passport) => {
var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromHeader("authorization");
opts.secretOrKey = database.secret;
// console.log(opts);
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    // console.log(jwt_payload);    
    User.findById(jwt_payload._id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));

}
```

My token is created here (this is the login endpoint):

```
router.post('/authUserCredentials', (req, res, next)=>{
    var userCred = req.body;
    // console.log(userCred); 

    controllers.checkUserExist({email : req.body.email}, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            controllers.failResponse(res, "Something went wrong. Please try again.");
        }else if(!data){
            controllers.failResponse(res, "You Are Not Registered. Please Register to Continue.");
        }else{
            var passMatch = controllers.comparePassword(userCred.password, data.password);
            // console.log(passMatch); 
            if(!passMatch){
                controllers.failResponse(res, "Invalid Email or Password. Please try again.");
            }else{
                var token = jwt.sign(data.toJSON(), database.secret, {expiresIn: 604800});
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: "Login Successful.",
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My passport route to get the user profile (after user has logged in):

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

My token is stored at the local storage after submitting the form and valid response here:

```
authUserCredentials()
  {
    console.log(this.loginUser.value);
    var email = this.loginUser.value.email.toLowerCase().trim();
    var password = this.loginUser.value.password.trim();

    var loginUserData = {email, password};
    console.log(loginUserData);

    this.userServ.authUser(loginUserData).subscribe((data:any) => {
      if(!data.success){
        this.flashMsg.show("ERROR : "+ data.msg, {cssClass: 'flashMessageBox', timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }else{
        this.userServ.storeToken(data.token);
        this.flashMsg.show("SUCCESS : "+ data.msg, {cssClass: 'flashMessageBox', timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['user/profile']);
      }      
    })
  }
```

My profile Component at angular:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userServ.getUserProfile().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.user = data.user;
      // console.log(data);      
    },err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Get user profile service and store token and get token function:

```
getUserProfile(){
    let header = new HttpHeaders();
    var token = this.getToken();
    // console.log(token); 
    header.append('Authorization', token);   
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
    // console.log(header);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: header}).map(res => {return res});
  }



  storeToken(token){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
  }


  getToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  }
```

Comment: Hi .. Sorry i Can't see WHERE YOU CALL the storeToken() method after login success ...

Comment: Have you tried this: header.append('Authorization Bearer', token);  I think you need 'Bearer' in the header.

Comment: no it does not working.

Comment: why it's working on postman, but not working when i'm trying to do with browser.

Comment: If it works in postman, then it means your angular code is not submitting the post request correctly. Are you sure that the body of the request is formatted as correct JSON as expected by Passport. ie. does console.log(loginUserData); show the correct JSON?

Comment: You say ''http://localhost:3000/users/profile'' is your auth route, but it is not. That is your get user profile route. Please read this blog to see the difference: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314  Where is your /login route?

Comment: guys plz try to solve this one also:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354256/showing-unauthorized-after-submitting-registration-form-in-node-js?noredirect=1#comment126123970_71354256

Answer (score 1):

change your profile service functions header append like this

```
header = header.append('Authorization', token);   
header =  header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

first go to authinterceptor.ts
replace the existing code with above code

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../user/user-services/user.service";




    @Injectable()
    export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    
        constructor(private userService : UserService,private router : Router){}
    
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    
            if (req.headers.get('noauth'))
                return next.handle(req.clone());
            else {
                const clonedreq = req.clone({
                    headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", this.userService.loadToken())
                });
                return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
                    tap(
                        event => { },
                        err => {
                            if (err.error.auth == false) {
                                this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                            }
                        })
                );
            }
        }
    }
```