# showing "Unauthorized" after submitting registration form in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am doing a project of registration/login where I have took 2 collections student and teacher. After submitting the registration  form it has to redirect `/secret` page but it shows me ***Unauthorized*** and the mail and password is storing in user collection instead of teacher collection. Plz help me to fix this bug. And also plz tell how to add teacher information in teacher collection and student information in student collection.

**Thank U in Advance...**

Code:-

```
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const ejs=require("ejs");
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

// const md5=require("md5");

const session=require("express-session")
const passport=require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose")

const app=express();


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.use(session({
    secret:"Our little secret.",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())


// for student
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/WceDB");
// const student=mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/studentDB");
// const teacher=mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/facultyDB");

// const { User, Teacher } = require('./model.js');


const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    }
})
const teacherSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    Teacher_email:{
        type:String
    },
    Teacher_password:{
        type:String
    }
})




userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
teacherSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User=new mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
const Teacher=new mongoose.model("Teacher",teacherSchema)



passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

passport.use(Teacher.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(Teacher.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Teacher.deserializeUser());

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
})
app.get("/student-home",function(req,res){
    res.render("student-home");
})
app.get("/faculty-home",function(req,res){
    res.render("faculty-home");
})
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
})
app.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
})
app.get("/faculty-login",function(req,res){
    res.render("faculty-login");
})
app.get("/faculty-register",function(req,res){
    res.render("faculty-register");
})
app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/");
})
app.get("/fun-page",function(req,res){
    res.render("fun-page")
})

app.get("/secrets",function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("secrets");
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})

app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
})


app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    User.register({username:req.body.username},req.body.password,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/fun-page");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }
    })
})
app.post("/faculty-register",function(req,res){
    Teacher.register({username:req.body.username},req.body.password,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/fun-page");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }
    })
})

app.post("/login",function(req,res){
    const user=new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    req.login(user,function(err){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }
    })


})
app.post("/faculty-login",function(req,res){
    const user=new Teacher({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    req.login(user,function(err){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets")
            })
        }
    })
})


app.listen(3000 || process.env.PORT,function(){
    console.log('on my way...');
})
```

error or final result:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6Yx.png)

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback from your error message ?

Comment: done!!!
see the image description.

Comment: then this may help : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871761/http-localhost3000-users-profile-401-unauthorized)

Comment: hope so. btw thank u

Comment: not solved yet....
if u know someone who can solve this plz let him know